# denying access to S3 bucket except specific lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to add the below bucket policy that would deny access to the bucket for any (get, put, delete) operation except my AWS lambda. Can you please help why this is not working

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy#####",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::#####-s3-file-upload/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:5######1:function:temp_read_s3"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you want to deny access by any other way except one lambda ?

Comment: I want to allow access only to specific  lambda, and deny access to rest other who want to access s3 bucket

Comment: You are able to call this S3 using this lambda ? other object getting deny ? what is error you getting is while accessing S3 using lambda ?

Comment: yes i am able get object from lambda and other API when using "ArnEquals" but getting access denied with "ArnNotEquals". it is not able to identify my ARM for this lambda

Comment: What is issue with ArnEquals because this is correct way. You have to write policy to give access only to that lambda ARN.

Comment: with ArnEquals it is allowing all to access bucket and with ARNnotEquals, it is denying access to all . With ArnNotEquals it should allow access only to my lambda.  I am assuming it is not able to identify my lambda with ARN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201252/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-user7006069).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create lambda execution role for lambda.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-s3-file-upload",
            "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-s3-file-upload/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Step 2: Add that role to lambda 
Step 3: Add that role to S3 policy to restrict only that role.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "S3 Access Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2XXXXXXXXX:role/executionrole"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::sample_bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::sample_bucket/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

[image]

This way you can restrict only specific lambda. For other lambda you can use different execution role.

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 1):

solution for lambda is to add an assumed role. With a bit of digging and troubleshooting, I realized that the Lambda function assumes the role you provide, and that assumed role must also be added to the S3 bucket policy as below.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::55account_id111:role/iam_policy_role",
                    "arn:aws:sts::55account_id111:assumed-role/#####_lambda_role/lambda_function"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [ "s3:GetObject",
                        "s3:PutObject",
                        "s3:DeleteObject" ]
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::######-bucketName/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::######-bucketName"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`